# SetState won't update with callback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, es6-class

I'm having hard time understanding why the text won't change in browser or why it won't even `console.log` the new state. I'm just trying to change the text by clicking on it.

```
class Komponentti extends React.Component{
      constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {teksti: "Hello"}
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
      }
      handleClick(){
        this.setState = ({teksti: "Mello"}), function(){
          console.log(this.state.teksti);
        }
      }  
      render(){
          return(
            <h1 onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.state.teksti}</h1>
          )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling it wrong. Should be:

```
handleClick() {
 this.setState({teksti: "Mello"}), () => {
    console.log(this.state.teksti);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ohh I was looking at this for so long and couldn't figure out what was different. It's missing =. Thank you

Comment: @sander np. Happens to all of us

Answer (score 1):

May be you have been confused with es6 fat arrow functions.

In ES6 we can declare the functions using fat arrow notation to pass the lexical `this` to the function you declare.

Eg:

```
const example = () => {
    // Something interesting
}
```

But we call that function as `example()`.

But the `setState()` is an asynchronous function already declared in the React.
We can use it to update the state in the following manner.

```
handleClick(){
 this.setState({teksti: "Mello"}), () => {
    console.log(this.state.teksti);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below are the way to set state :

1. this.setState({valuename:"value"});
2. this.state.varluename = "value";
   this.forceUpdate();

Comment: Oh wow, does forceupdate make it render the new value to the dom?